# Why does Silver form bonds with covalent character?

Tags: bond, covalent-compounds, silver, hsab

Compounds of silver form particularly strong bonds which is accounted for by the significant covalent character of the bonding. Furthermore, is the tendency to form covalent bonds linked to the fact that $\ce{Ag+}$ is a soft acid?

Comment: related: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/16261/metal-compounds-that-bond-covalently?rq=1, http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/429/why-do-magnesium-and-lithium-form-covalent-organometallic-compounds?rq=1

Comment: Silver compounds, if anything, are usually **more** ionic than those of its closest neighbors.