# Bond type in Grignard reagent

Tags: bond, grignard-reagent

I just want to confirm if the $\ce{R-Mg}$ bond is a covalent bond which undergoes heterolytic fission during reactions while the bond between magnesium and halogen atom is ionic. Am I right or wrong?

Comment: The R-magnesium bond in a Grignard reagent is polar covalent with carbon being the negative end of the dipole, which explains its nucleophilicity. And the magnesium-halogen bond is largely ionic.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/429/why-do-magnesium-and-lithium-form-covalent-organometallic-compounds

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. The carbon-magnesium bond in a Grignard reagent is polar covalent with carbon being the negative end of the dipole, which explains its nucleophilicity and the magnesium-halogen bond is largely ionic.

[image]

([image source](https://chemistryscore.com/grignard-reagent-mechanism/))